# Set origin of Box2d Body LIBGDX

Tags: box2d

I want to rotate Body with two fixtures. By default when you call body.setAngularVelocity() Body rotates around center of all fixtures. Can i change center of a body to rotate all fixtures around my point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible to do with the `setAngularVelocity` as it sets only rotation of body not relative to other points or bodies. You can probably use distance or revolute joints to set the point around which you want the body to rotate. Then to apply angular velocity you can use `applyImpulse` in direction where you want the body to rotate.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't believe i can get any answers about libgdx on this site